# Why on click of a input button using JavaScript i am getting my asp.net page refreshed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am using an html image button type like this:

```
<input id="wbsupld" type="image" value="upload" onclick="showwbsdiv()" src="images/Upload.png">
```

and the javascript function is:

```
 function showwbsdiv() {
        document.getElementById("masswbsupld").style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
```

which is displaying a div "masswbsupld" but the problem is my page is getting refreshed and the div goes back to display="none" mode.

and i am using update panel .. is that causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because its type is `image`, an `image` input element will submit your form.

You need to do

```
onclick="return showwbsdiv();"
```